# SAML Response authentication

Tags: salesforce, saml

Scenario:

1. Browser(User) requests resource from Service Provider (SP).
2. SP Redirects (with SAML Request) to Identity Provider (IdP).
3. Since it is first login, User gives the (IdP) his/her valid credentials.
4. IdP then redirects Browser (with SAML Response which includes SAML token) to the SP page.
5. Application has a link to different application. The Second application needs to validate the user credentials with the same IdP.

User clicks on that link and browser opens the second application. Browser contains the same SAML response from SP.

In **Step 5** how can I authenticate the user with SAML response and allow the user to be logged in automatically.

**Do I need another SP?** 
I will not be able to use the SP from step 1 as it is external application.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If the second application is in a different administrative domain, it should be done through its own SAML SP starting another SAML request/response exchange with the IDP. If it is in the same domain you may be able to pass an intra-domain credential such as a cookie between the first application and the second (or rely on full SAML as well). You would never reuse the same SAML response because that is meant to be one-time use only.

Comment: Hans Thanks for your response.  say abc.com & xyz.com use same IDP server. As per web browser SSO User needs to enter their user credentials only one place and if the user goes to the next application , how it get authenticated. What will be the SAML request here? In my case both domains are same, but the calls happens from external sites.

Comment: abc.com and xyz.com point to the same IDP; the apps can be unrelated and don't need to be aware of each other to achieve SSO between those apps; you would go from A to B just like you would go directly to B

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My issue now is each app asks for login credentails once. I use  SP initiated with secureAuth IdP. Is there any configuration required for auto login?